# draw multiple lines on top of the gantt chart d3.js

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I am building this Gantt chart that I found an example for on the blocks:

https://bl.ocks.org/arpitnarechania/4b4aa79b04d2e79f30765674b4c24ace

It works pretty well. I just want to add a vertical line on top of the "tasks", to indicate some other event that happened while the task was in progress. The idea is to draw a vertical line across the rectangle: 
[image]

The only thing that I am not sure is how to handle drawing multiple lines from the array of time stamps. I know that currently I am using `d.synched[0]` hence just a single line, but how do i change that to draw as many lines as there are time stamps.

Here's my JSBIN: https://jsbin.com/layecehidu/edit?js,console,output

Any, and all help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution, without changing your code too much, is creating a group for each object in `data`:

```
var lineGroup = svg.selectAll(null)
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("g");
```

And then creating the lines based on those groups' data:

```
var lines = lineGroup.selectAll(null)
    .data(function(d) {
        return d.synched
    })
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .style("stroke", "red")
    .attr("x1", function(d) {
        console.log(d);
        return x(parseDate(d));
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
        var parentDatum = d3.select(this.parentNode).datum();
        return y(parentDatum.category) - 5;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
        return x(parseDate(d));
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
        var parentDatum = d3.select(this.parentNode).datum();
        return y(parentDatum.category) + y.rangeBand() + 5;
    });
```

Here is the updated code:

```js
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

var data = [{
  "category": "Task 1",
  "from": "1-Jan-17",
  "to": "15-Jan-17",
  "progress": 100,
  "synched": ["5-Jan-17", "7-Jan-17"]
}, {
  "category": "Task 2",
  "from": "13-Jan-17",
  "to": "1-Feb-17",
  "progress": 60,
  "synched": ["15-Jan-17"]
}, {
  "category": "Task 1",
  "from": "1-Feb-17",
  "to": "11-Mar-17",
  "progress": 90,
  "synched": ["2-Feb-17", "4-Feb-17"]
}]

var types_of_statuses = ["Completed", "Remaining"];
var statuses_color = ["#2ecc71", "#e74c3c"];

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.from = parseDate(d.from);
  d.to = parseDate(d.to);
});
var margin = {
    top: 50,
    right: 50,
    bottom: 50,
    left: 100
  },
  width = 900 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .rangeRoundBands([0, height], 0.2);

var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);

y.domain(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.category;
}));
x.domain([d3.min(data, function(d) {
  return d.from;
}), d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.to;
})]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom")
  .ticks(15)
  .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%d%b"));

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.category);
  })
  .attr("height", y.rangeBand())
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.from);
  })
  .attr("width", function(d) {
    return x(d.to) - x(d.from);
  });

var lineGroup = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g");

var lines = lineGroup.selectAll(null)
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.synched
  })
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .style("stroke", "red")
  .attr("x1", function(d) {
    return x(parseDate(d));
  })
  .attr("y1", function(d) {
    var parentDatum = d3.select(this.parentNode).datum();
    return y(parentDatum.category) - 5;
  })
  .attr("x2", function(d) {
    return x(parseDate(d));
  })
  .attr("y2", function(d) {
    var parentDatum = d3.select(this.parentNode).datum();
    return y(parentDatum.category) + y.rangeBand() + 5;
  });


svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis)
  .append("text")
  .attr("x", width - margin.right)
  .attr("dx", ".71em")
  .attr("dy", "-0.2em")
  .text("Date");

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);
```

```css
.pending {
        fill: #e74c3c;
    }

    .bar {
        fill: #2ecc71;
    }

/*     .bar:hover, .pending:hover {
      fill: #3498db;
    } */

    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    .legend {
        padding: 5px;
        font: 16px sans-serif;
        background: yellow;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #888;
    }

    .tooltip {
        background: #eee;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999999;
        color: #333;
        font-size: 12px;
        left: 130px;
        padding: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        top: 95px;
        z-index: 10;
        display: block;
        opacity: 0;
    }
.axis,
.frame {
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

    .axis path {
        fill: none;
        stroke: grey;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    .axis text {
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 10px;
    }

    .axis line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: grey;
        stroke-width: 1;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Notice that, for getting the `category` of each line, we have to access the parent's data (that is, the group) in the line selection.

Another option, if you want, is populating the line's data with the parent's (the group) data, like this:

```
var lines = lineGroup.selectAll(null)
    .data(function(d) {
        return d.synched.map(function(e) {
            return {
                syn: e,
                cat: d.category
            };
        })
    })
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .style("stroke", "red")
    .attr("x1", function(d) {
        return x(parseDate(d.syn));
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
        return y(d.cat) - 5;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
        return x(parseDate(d.syn));
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
        return y(d.cat) + y.rangeBand() + 5;
    });
```

Comment: Which one would you recommend? Is there a difference in performance?

Comment: Intuitively, I'd say that the second one is faster. But you can always test them: https://jsperf.com/

Comment: Is there a way to add text in these blocks?

Comment: Yes, there is a way.